# PysimpleSOAP - invalid args structure

Tags: python, wsdl, pysimplesoap

I encountered problem with calling webservice method, I have

```
client = SoapClient(wsdl="address")
countries = {'countryCode':1, 'webapiKey':'apiKey'};
client.doGetCountries(**countries)
```

but I'm getting error

`ValueError: Invalid Args Structure. Errors: ["type mismatch for value. master(<class 'dict'>): {'DoGetCountriesRequest': *{'countryCode': <class 'int'>, 'webapiKey': <class 'str'>}*}, test(<class 'dict'>): {'DoGetCountriesRequest': {'webapiKey': 'webapi', 'countryCode': 1}}"]`

So I suppose I'm providing incorrect args structure but I don't know how to fix that?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does putting `1` into the quotes help? `countries = {'countryCode': '1', 'webapiKey':'apiKey'}`

Comment: no, I think there's sth wrong with this `*` in master(<class 'dict'>)`

Comment: Closed. I switched library to suds.